# Angular 2: How to write nested Loop inside tag-input

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Using Angular 2 I'm trying to use tag-input to show parent child object as the following :

```
<tag-input *ngFor="let obj of objInputs" [ngModel]="[obj]" [modelAsStrings]="true" [editable]='false' #input>
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
    <!-- DEFINE HERE YOUR TEMPLATE -->
    <div>
      {{obj.ParentOfParentvalue}} / <span *ngFor="let child of obj.children"> {{child.Parentvalue}} {{child.value}} <delete-icon (click)="onItemRemoved(child, index)"></delete-icon></span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</tag-input>
```

the above code is working in 2 level, but when I tried to add the loop in the third level nothing appeared as following :

```
<tag-input *ngFor="let obj of objInputs" [ngModel]="[obj]" [modelAsStrings]="true" [editable]='false' #input>
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
    <!-- DEFINE HERE YOUR TEMPLATE -->
    <div>
      {{obj.ParentOfParentvalue}} / <span *ngFor="let child of obj.children"> {{child.Parentvalue}}</span> :<span *ngFor="let lastchild of child.children"> {{lastchild.value}} <delete-icon (click)="onItemRemoved(child, index)"></delete-icon></span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</tag-input>
```

any help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the 3rd loop is not nested inside the `<span *ngFor="let child of obj.children">`

If you do not nest it properly, then Angular will try to find `child` object in different context. And because it does not find it, it has nothing to display